# webpack doesnt add prototype function to Object from other file

Tags: javascript, webpack, prototype, es6-modules

I have a file containing the definition of a Object and in that same file I have a function that is part of this object like so:

```
export function ARScene(_callbacks) {

   this.callbacksObject = _callbacks;
   // more fancy code.. 
}

ARScene.prototype.changeCar = function() {
    //some fancy code here 
    this.loadHDCar(); // THIS LIKE GENERATES A ERROR. 
}
```

now I have a different file containing an other method that is part of the Object called `ARScene` like so:

```
import { ARScene } from './arScene';

ARScene.prototype.loadHDCar = function() {
     //some more fancy code..
}
```

What is happening when I build this with webpack and run it in the browser I get the error that `this.loadHDCar();` is `undefined` I guess this happens because webpack doesnt add a file if it is not imported. But how do I make sure that `ARScene.prototype.loadHDCar` is added to the object in the final output?

I am a complete newbie to webpack and modules. I have found answers on stackoverflow about this but they had slightly different scenarios then me. So their solutions didnt work (or maybe I didnt understand it).

If more context or information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Why did you define that method in a different file in the first place? It's really weird to split up a class like that, making your code hard to discover.

Comment: How did you make sure `ARScene` refers to the constructor in the separate file? Did you `import` it?

Comment: because that class is really big and it gets messy in one file

Comment: Then move helper functions (that you can `import`) to different files, but do not move entire method definitions. Or split the class into smaller objects to make it less messy.

Comment: @Bergi see edit regarding your first comment, regarding your second comment could you give an example of what you mean with that?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your dependencies (imports) are inverted. The class should depend on the method, not the other way round.

Comment: alright, I think I understand you, but just for me could you give an example on how to fix this? (if it is even fixable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make sure that `ARScene.prototype.loadHDCar` is added to the object in the final output?

You should import it in the *arScene* module, and you should even create the prototype method in there (where you are defining the class) for visibility.

```
export function loadHDCar() {
    … //some more fancy code
}
```

```
import { loadHDCar } from './loadHDCar';

export function ARScene(_callbacks) {
    …
}
ARScene.prototype.loadHDCar = loadHDCar;
ARScene.prototype.changeCar = function() {
    … // some fancy code here 
    this.loadHDCar();
};
```